# RedisTemplate.convertAndSend causes 'IllegalArgumentException: non-public interface is not defined by the given loader' in spring-data-redis:2.4.2

Tags: spring-data-redis

After I upgrade `spring-boot` to 2.4.1, which includes `spring-data-redis:2.4.2`, the following error causes:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: non-public interface is not
> defined by the given loader   at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.mapToModule(Proxy.java:798)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.(Proxy.java:630)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.lambda$getProxyConstructor$1(Proxy.java:426)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$$Lambda$222/0000000000000000.apply(Unknown
> Source) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue$Memoizer.get(AbstractClassLoaderValue.java:329)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue.computeIfAbsent(AbstractClassLoaderValue.java:205)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyConstructor(Proxy.java:424)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:1006)
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:126)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]     at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:118)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]     at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:97)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]     at
> org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.createConnectionSplittingProxy(RedisConnectionUtils.java:230)
> ~[spring-data-redis-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]  at
> org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:151)
> ~[spring-data-redis-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]  at
> org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:105)
> ~[spring-data-redis-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]  at
> org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:209)
> ~[spring-data-redis-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]  at
> org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:189)
> ~[spring-data-redis-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]  at
> org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.convertAndSend(RedisTemplate.java:834)
> ~[spring-data-redis-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]

It happens even though I put `spring.aop.proxy-target-class: true` option in configurations. Because `RedisConnectionProxy` non-public interface was introduced in 2.4.2.

```
    interface RedisConnectionProxy extends RedisConnection, RawTargetAccess {

        /**
         * Return the target {@link RedisConnection} of this proxy.
         * <p>
         * This will typically be the native driver {@link RedisConnection} or a wrapper from a connection pool.
         *
         * @return the underlying {@link RedisConnection} (never {@link null}).
         */
        RedisConnection getTargetConnection();

    }
```

Comment: I ran into the same exception and created an issue in spring-data-redis: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/issues/2016